# Missing version in Fabric Crashlytics

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, google-fabric

Everytime I release a new version of an app, this version shows up in Fabric crashlytics service, and I can track crashes, non-fatals, etc.

My issue is that I released a version on monday (11/19/18) but the version number is not showing up in crashes version filter. The next version (not on the store yet, but on testflight) is showing tho.

I have no idea how this is possible, if it comes from changes in fabric/firebase, or if it's coming from me (I don't see a thing I did differently than usual).

I will take any hint, help, and similar cases from you guys.

I know this is not a question strictly about development but the forum button on fabric website redirect to SO.

Comment: I have the opposite - new version number immediately in the filter but no crash reports...

Comment: @Ewan maybe you haven't had any crashes for that version? Try forcing one and see if it shows up (see Crashlytics Docs)

Comment: @Kevin - my big problem was releasing using './gradlew installRelease' rather than 'Build > Generate signed....' in AS. All working now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53420776/crashlytics-not-uploading-mapping-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after some digging and help from Firebase/Fabric people, I've resolved this issue.

It appears that I had too many active versions for my app, Crashlytics was tracking too many versions and couldn't show some more.

After removing a few outdated versions, everything came back to normal and all the data were there retroactively.

I hope this post can be helpful for some people, I didn't manage to find any informations about that problem. It might be useful to put that piece of information in Fabric documentation.

Comment: How do you remove outdated versions from Crashlytics? I don't see an option for it. Was that by contacting Firebase support?

Comment: No, it's located under settings > APPS > your app > versions, and there you can remove the one you don't need.

Comment: @DamienBannerot can not find "versions" menu - could U pls clarify...?

Comment: Facing this in crashlytics in firebase as well, anyone has idea how to solve this on firebase

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was different.

The app I was updating had previously used **Fabric** Crashlytics. When updating the app I converted the integration over to the **Firebase** Crashlytics integration (deleted the API keys from the build script, removed the Fabric with statement in the App Delegate, etc.)

I confirmed with Crashlytics support that if you are updating an app that was initially integrated with Crashlytics using the **Fabric** docs then you must continue to use that integration even if you have connected your app to Firebase and now use Firebase.

I pushed an update out where I reverted back to the integration outlined in the Fabric docs, and I now have Crashlytics data for this version in Firebase and Fabric.

Comment: what if reverting back is not an option?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an iOS topic but I had the same issue with my Android app and only related topic is this one. I was not able to see latest build on filter after migration to Firebase Crashlytics.

How I solved is I've added:
`FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);` to my Application class right after FirebaseApp initialization `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext());`.

After that, build started to appear on filter.