# Crashlytics not uploading mapping file

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I'm able to see crashes for a release build in Crashlytics but they are still obfuscated. I'm using:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1"
implementation "com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.6"
```

and (project level)

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1' // Crashlytics plugin
    classpath "net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.15"
```

I've followed the instructions at https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-report, in particular I've deleted the `-printmapping <path>/mapping.txt` line from `config.txt`

When I look in the Crashlytics log I do not see an upload of the mapping file.

When I run a release build for an earlier version of my project using:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0"
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

and (project level)

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.24.4'
```

then I see unobfuscated stack traces and mapping upload messages in crashlytics.log:

```
2018-11-21 10:52:22.573 [DEBUG] (Daemon worker) com.crashlytics  - Deobfuscation file(s) uploaded.
```

Any ideas what's wrong? I don't see any of the mapping file related logs for the recent (not working) version in the Crashlytics log and I don't see the gradle upload task running in the gradle output whereas for the older (working) version I see the following:

```
:app:crashlyticsUploadDeobsRelease (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 1.28 secs.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argh. Well there was a simple fix, shame it took me so long to find it. I always (until now) build and locally install a release build using `./gradlew iR` (shortcut for `./gradlew installRelease`). I tried (after an embarrassingly long time) building from Android Studio instead (`Build > Generate Signed Bundle / Apk`). As soon as I did that it worked.

I'll update here if and when I figure out non-AS based releasing works with Crashlytics. Meanwhile if you're having problems take a look at the sample https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/crash.
You can take that, drop in your own google-services.json and release as above, then check `crashlytics.log` (see above) .

Comment: UPDATE: I'm now switched from Crashlytics to Sentry for crash reporting. It has many more features, a better reporting interface and unlike Crashlytics you can log / report from pure Java library dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Have you read here: https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/dex-and-proguard.html ?

I'm using those lines in my `proguard-rules.pro` file (inside your app folder) to get de-obfuscated crash reports

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
# prevent Crashlytics obfuscation
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**
```

And be sure to **not** have this line in your proguard file

```
-printmapping mapping.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I do have those lines in `proguard-rules.pro` and I don't have (indeed have never had) `-printmapping mapping.txt`. I did have a lingering `config.txt` file ( from earlier vn?) which had it and I deleted, to no effect. Now I have removed `config.txt`. I'm interested to see if others see `Deobfuscation file(s) uploaded.` in their crashlytics logs....

Comment: Where are you initializing Crashlytics? In a custom `Application` class?

Comment: Yes (but don't think it's needed now). Crashlytics is working in that it's sending the stack trace. The problem is the stack trace is obfuscated. If you search for `uploaded` in your crashlytics log you should see the upload logged. That's what's not happening for me. Make sense?
On Linux / Windows: ~/.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools/crashlytics.log
On Mac: ~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools/crashlytics.log

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that nothing on your network is blocking Crashlytics's host. For example PiHole.