# Crashlytics issue when updated from com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.8 to 2.9.9

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

During update of my android app, i updated all dependencies. When i tested the release build, i receive the following error:

E/CrashlyticsCore: **The Crashlytics build ID is missing. This occurs when Crashlytics tooling is absent from your app's build configuration. Please review Crashlytics onboarding instructions and ensure you have a valid Crashlytics account.**

Crashlytics is working fine for my previous release that is currently available on the play store.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53409645/6176003

Comment: Yes i checked many things including this one before asking for assistance here.

Comment: i use this implementation and i have no problem implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9@aar') {
        transitive = true
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    } .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

UPDATE: October 6, 2020

So a fix is available now for using Crashlytics. Follow this link from Firebase

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android

Earlier Accepted Answer.
After talking with fabric team, they told me that it is a known issue. To solve this, we have to include the
**apply plugin: 'io.fabric'**
in the build.gradle file of the app module. Including this will give the following warning:

> WARNING: API 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildProviders()'.
> It will be removed at the end of 2019.

You can ignore this warning for now. Hopefully a fix for this issue will be provided soon.

Comment: I still get the same exception, even with the plugin applied in the app module. Is app module enough or I should apply it other modules too?

Comment: I have 5 modules in my app. Personally, I have used crashlytics in the app module only and the "apply plugin" is needed for only this one module. Have you included the fabric dependency in the project level build.gradle file? If you can share the project level build.gradle file, it will be helpful.

Comment: I needed to update gradle plugin, it was locked on the older version. Updating resolved the issue

Answer (score 3):

It is fixed in the latest version, you can update your version with 1.28.0.

```
buildscript {
  // ... repositories, etc. ...

   dependencies {
       // ...other dependencies ...
       classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0'
   }
}
```

Comment: I am using classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.1. Still getting same warning

Comment: Still giving the same warning for me.

Comment: why not try with classpath `'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0'`

Comment: what is your android studio version? You used 3.3.2 android studio, that's the time it's work perfectly.

Comment: This fixed the issue. Well, you can actually ignored it as per @wj07's answer but if the error message is annoying for you, just update the fabric tool version to `1.28.0`